# Create a GCP alert using Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to create a monitoring alert, using a service account in Google Cloud.  But there does not seem to be any allowance for using a SA in alert creation.  This shows in bigquery scheduled query as a drop down to select SA, but the same feature is not available for alerting.
Do suggest if any possibility of implementing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is a way to create Alert Policies via [API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-api#api-create-policy) calls. It is currently in Beta.

However, I was able to create an Alert Policy passing the variables as below. In that case, both the caller and service account should have a “Service Account Token Creator” IAM role to perform this operation.

$ gcloud alpha monitoring policies create --impersonate-service-account="[ServiceAccount]" --policy-from-file="[example.json]"

You might find this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/monitoring/policies/create) helpful and recommend you to go through it to help serve your purpose.